# SQL Count number of times value appears in particular column in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ok here is my problem I am trying to create a view that counts how many times a particular value is used in another table.

My View is like this

```
SELECT 
table1.id AS code_id,
table2.asset_standard_id,
       Count(table2.pkey) AS COUNT
FROM table1  LEFT JOIN table2 
ON table2.code_id = table1.Id
where table1.code_type = (select pkey from imtbl_code_type where imtbl_code_type.id = 'A-Problem') and table2.asset_standard_id = '25209-45MEO'
GROUP BY table1.id,
table2.asset_standard_id
order by count
```

and this returns the count, but my problem is I also want to show zeros as well.

I do not think it is possible, but any help would be appreciated, I am at a loss.

Thanks!

Update (thanks for input :) ) This is a view that will be called by passing in the asset_standard_id, so I am not sure if I can do a On there.

Here is some sample for it
the client will enter in an asset_standard_id of 25209-45MEO through a c# interface into Active Reports. this view will then execute to return all occurances that are found, plus ones that are not.

```
Table 1                        ||   table 2
---------------------------------
Code  | asset_standard_id       ||  Code
----------------------------------------------
c1      25209-45MEO            ||  c1
c3      25209-45MEO            ||  c2
c3      25209-45MEO            ||  c3

And what I would love to see in the results are:
code_id || asset_standard_id || count
c3           25209-45MEO         2
c1           25209-45MEO         1
c2           25209-45MEO         0
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Thanks, updated as requested! You are aawesome sir

Answer (score 1):

The condition on the *second* table needs to be in the `on` clause:

```
select t1.id AS code_id, t2.asset_standard_id,
       Count(t2.pkey) as cnt
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t2.code_id = t1.Id and
        t2.asset_standard_id = '25209-45MEO'
where t1.code_type = (select ict.pkey from imtbl_code_type ict where ict.id = 'A-Problem')
group by t1.id, t2.asset_standard_id
order by cnt;
```

Note that I changed the query to use table aliases.  This makes the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: Sorry type-o i meant can you use a on Clause in a view where the asset_standard_id is what the client will be searching on?

Comment: @Ganthur . . . You can use an `on` clause in a view.  I don't really understand your question.  A query using a view can have a `where` clause that filters on any column returned by the view.

Comment: yes but the on clause is being filtered by the asset_standard_id = '25209-45meo' however that is the value that will be dynamic (passed into the view)

Comment: @Ganthur . . . You don't pass values into a view.  If you are defining a table-valued function that takes an argument, then you have no problem.

Comment: Sorry i know I am confusing you. but the client will be executing this view through an interface with a filter of asset_standard_id. So they will do this     select * from imvw_count_view where asset_standard_id =....   so because of that I cannot set the on in the view to equal a specific asset_standard_id. clear as mud? :)

Comment: @Ganthur . . . You should ask *another* question and explain what the real situation is.  That question is quite different from this question.